# Need help to write a SQL query?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a SQL table with column which contain string like 'type|type1|type2|type3|type4'.
I need to select the string, id. Split string and insert to another table. First item should be default and I need to get identity of it and insert to another table with the type value.

Please help me to create T-SQL query to accomplish desirable result.

Example

**Step 1** To select Items from Table 1. 
**Step 2** Split to array
**Step 3** Insert to **Table 2** (first item will be default) 
**Step 4** Update **Table 1** with default Type Value based on TypeID and Default True

**Table 1**

```
ID       Items                           Default
--------------------------------------------------
1        type|type1|type2|type3|type4
2        type|type1|type2|type3|type4
```

**Table 2**

```
ID   TypeID        Type    Default(bool)
--------------------------------------------------
1    1             type1   1
2    1             type2   0
```

Comment: Fix your database design - [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) it!

Comment: Thank you for valuable suggestion

Comment: Were you doing this to normalize it?  Or did you just encounter a problem and need to multi-valued column gone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the split function from Arnold Fribble's answer on [this thread](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=50648)

```
Create FUNCTION dbo.Split (@sep char(1), @s varchar(512))
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
    WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
      SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + 1)
      FROM Pieces
      WHERE stop > 0
    )
    SELECT pn,
      SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 512 END) AS s
    FROM Pieces
  )
GO
```

You can write the following (I made some guesses about the ID field in table2 and what the defaultTypeID should be in table1 but you should be able to adjust that)

```
CREATE TABLE #table1       ( 
     id            INT, 
     items         VARCHAR(MAX), 
     defaulttypeid INT 
  ) 

CREATE TABLE #table2       ( 
     id        INT IDENTITY, 
     typeid    INT, 
     TYPE      VARCHAR(5), 
     isdefault BIT 
  ) 

INSERT INTO #table1 
VALUES      (1, 
             'type|type1|type2|type3|type4', 
             NULL), 
            (2, 
             'type|type1|type2|type3|type4', 
             NULL) 


INSERT INTO #table2 
            (typeid, 
             TYPE, 
             isdefault) 
SELECT id             typeid, 
       Rtrim(split.s) AS item, 
       CASE 
         WHEN ( split.pn = 1 ) THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
       END            AS isdefault 
FROM   #table1 
       CROSS APPLY test.dbo.Split('|', items) AS split 

UPDATE #table1 
SET    defaulttypeid = t2.ID
FROM   #table1 t1 
       INNER JOIN #table2 t2 
         ON t1.id = t2.typeid 
            AND t2.isdefault = 1 


DROP TABLE #table1 

DROP TABLE #table2
```

This outputs

```
ID          Items                          DefaultTypeID
----------- ------------------------------ -------------
1           type|type1|type2|type3|type4    1     
2           type|type1|type2|type3|type4    6



ID          TypeID      Type  IsDefault
----------- ----------- ----- ---------
1           1           type  1
2           1           type1 0
3           1           type2 0
4           1           type3 0
5           1           type4 0
6           2           type  1
7           2           type1 0
8           2           type2 0
9           2           type3 0
10          2           type4 0
```

Comment: Which way is more sufficient if I have in one table about 600K records and another a more than 600K

Comment: @Michael. If I had to guess I would say mine is. Ash's requires a seperate insert for each records so thats 600K transactions. Mine is two 1 insert and 1 update. SQL server can make that efficient. However I recommend you try both with a smaller set and see.

Comment: Ok I will try. I just found the issue in first example.  For some reason it copy not all items, on one less than it's suppose to be. Instead of 5 it copied 4. Last item from string is missing

Answer (score 2):

Though I totally disagree with the use of cursors I can't think of another way. This solution isn't tested but It looks like it should be ok.

```
DECLARE @pos INT
DECLARE @id INT
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @default INT
DECLARE @substring VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE tempCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT id, string
    FROM table_name

OPEN tempCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM tempCursor
    INTO @id, @string

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @default = 1
SET @pos = CHARINDEX('|', @string)
WHILE (@pos <> 0)
BEGIN
    SET @substring = SUBSTRING(@string, 1, @pos - 1)
    INSERT INTO table_name2(typeid, type, default) VALUES (@id, @substring, @default)
    SET @string = substring(@string, @pos+1, LEN(@string))
    SET @pos = charindex('|', @string)
    SET @default = 0
END

FETCH NEXT FROM tempCursor
    INTO @id, @string
END

CLOSE EWSCursor;
DEALLOCATE EWSCursor;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are genius. I have tested on dev database. Looks like it works. Thank you a lot

Comment: +1 for comming up with the correct answer but I did post a non-cursor implementation, since you seemed to want to see one

Comment: Ash could you please update your example. For some reason it copy not all items, on one less than it's suppose to be. Instead of 5 it copied 4